# Explain constraints on Specialization and Generalization

Tags: database, erd

This question I found in my DBMS college question paper. I am confused whether it belongs to ER Diagram topic or something else. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It is related to whole DBMS processes and knowledge specially part of DBMS architecture/design process.
For the detailed explanation over the topic, yes this unbend under UML diagrams - ER diagrams.